# Error on fnDeleteRow in jQuery dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

In Datatable, when i try to delete a row using fnDeleteRow, its raising an error.
"TypeError: e is undefined : in datatable.js file"

But at the same time the row is successfully getting deleted.

Any help?

```
     "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
        if(aData[0]=='Total')
        {
            var oTable = $('#data_table').dataTable();
            oTable.fnDeleteRow( nRow); 
        }
      }
```

I will get Total details also from the database. i will show that total in footer and wanted to delete the total row from displaying.

Comment: Please Put some code you have tried...

Comment: Please check i have added the code.